# Android Studio Project detected in Cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a cordova project in Command Line ,I have added android platform.
When run "**cordova prepare android**" or "**cordova build android**".

I get the following message "**Android Studio project Detected**" and build is not getting started, what will be the Issue kindly Help.

Cordova version : 8.0.0

Comment: That message has nothing to do with the problem, try also using --verbose in the commands, it should give you more details

Comment: Has this problem been resolved?

Comment: Yes changed the path for JDK in environment variables

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. you can run `$ cordova requirements` into your folder project to see the dependencies and solve them.

Comment: Why you wrote the answer in two languages?

Comment: @Mehdi Because i speak in spanish. But in Colombia de majority of people don't know to read english or always search answers in spanish, so, i decided to post my answer for the both type of programers or speakers :)

Comment: For that there is: https://es.stackoverflow.com/. The question was asked in english. The answer should be in english.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, it started after updating my Cordova version to 8.0. Fixed mine by running : `cordova build android --verbose` 
and discovered that the actual issue was with a plugin's after prepare hook script execution. Solved mine by removing the plugin - you can try removing plugins and adding latest stable version if plugins are crucial to your project.

Comment: Nice. Found an issue with one of installed plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.I am using ubuntu 16. I typed `cordova requirements` and it turned out I didn't have gradle installed. So I installed gradle and wham! it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. To fix it I removed nearly every line from my config.xml file, then tried to build. It worked with a nearly empty config.xml, so I slowly added the lines back in until I determined the one that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My issue was fixed by installing a JDK. I used openjdk-jdk-1.8.0_112 that was bundled with Android Studio. If you already have Studio installed you just need to add javac to your PATH. `<install-path>/android-studio/jre/bin/javac` on Ubuntu.

EDIT 01: The first run of `cordova build android` took 20 minutes. It had to install the latest Android SDK (26.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading the JAVA oracle 1.8 from [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

-Make sure to download the correct version for your operating system.

-Make sure that you include its path in the environment variable.

-Even if you put the path in the environment variable, double check the path by the echo command before building.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after updating to cordova version 8.0.0

First solution:
I downgraded to the previous cordova version `npm install -g cordova@7.1.0`

Second solution:
with cordova version 8.0.0 after running `cordova build android --verbose`, I found that execution stops when executing a script for the fcm-plugin. I removed the plugin and it worked, later updated the plugin too.

`This app does not have splash screens defined
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-fcm for hook "after_prepare": plugins\cordova-plugin-fcm\scripts\fcm_config_files_process.js`

Answer (score 0):

Please note I am not a programmer . I am ex Banker and entrepreneur now .I got really frustrated while setting cordova with all those errors  for building android apps in windows. Though, I now understand this is the simplest cake, if you know the know-how. I love coding, so I am sharing the whole length of steps .  You can figure out what step you are missing.

**Step 1. Requirements :**

- (a)node js ( npm )-- install it
- (b) Install cordova by command -->
   npm install -g cordova
- (c) Install Phone gap by command --> npm
    install -g phonegap
- (d) Ant apache ( download bin  not source ) by visiting

https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi . Keep this in C:/ Program files

- (e) JDK version 8 . you can down load previous version by visiting
  oracle.com

---

**NOTE : Keep ( ANT ) and JDK in Same Folder i.e extracted (d) and (e) in C:/Program files**

---

**Step: 2 Setting Environment Variables**
you can visit : Control Panel\System and Security\System--> environment variables You can see two types of windows : User and System

User Environment Variables:
You have to set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME

Add new variable :
Variable name :ANT_ HOME
Variable value : C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3

Variable name :JAVA_ HOME
Variable value :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

System Environment Variables: edit path and at the end use ; and paste ant/bin address
PATH :
Variable name :path
Variable value :....C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3\bin

---

**NOTE : Check ant & java configuration by windows command prompt :
ant -version and java --version . If using git then git --version.
If you error free then proceed further.**

---

**Step 3. Create a cordova project**
something like this command: cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

**Step 4. create platform android or ios: ensure proper config.xml**

**Step 5. now check cordova requirements: This work in app folder only **

Now build your app.

**Other errors you get if you miss these:**

- check  ="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" in config xml.
- Add Required Plugin - cordova plugin add -- as you need in config.xml
- Cordova requirements: This work in app folder only
- Cant find the Ant Version: you have not used ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME folder name.Ensure ANT_Home and JAVA_HOME only in User folder while the path in System Variable. Never use / " or ' in writing these variables.

"IF YOU DONT REQUIRE ANT AND GIT ---> Dont download it "

Hope this helps beginners and code layman like me.

[Cordova Project from Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895018/cordova-project-from-github/49948968#49948968)