# Cordova android build error - "Android Studio project detected"

Tags: android, cordova, build

I have created a cordova project and I'm trying to run `cordova build android` and get the output 'Android Studio project detected' with no further success.

The similar issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090990/android-studio-project-detected-in-cordova-project) has no solutions that work for me.

Here is a verbose output from `cordova build android --verbose`:

`No scripts found for hook "before_run".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Android Studio project detected
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /home/sb/App/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "App" to /home/sb/App/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "com.example.myapp" to /home/sb/App/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/MainActivity.java
This app does not have launcher icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `cordova requirements` it will show you, if something is missing. Correct problems (maybe JAVA_HOME variable is missing) and you will be able to finish your build.